# JMeter - MVC : Form posting model that contains dymanic data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jmeter

Trying to use jmeter to web stress my website. I want to post the page using Jmeter but it has to pass a model that is dymanic data that is generated when that page is loaded. There is also some form data that is passed.

Any ideas how i do this in Jmeter?

Thanks in Advance

Sleeper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `regular expression extractor` to scrape the data for re-use.  Your structure would look like this:

```
- GET PAGE
-- Regular Expression Extractor
- SUBMIT PAGE
```

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor